# JIRA dashboard integration using REST APIs

Tags: jira-rest-api

Is it possible to get the data of the JIRA dashboard in the JSON format using REST APIS? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the dashboard info: https://jira-server/rest/api/2/dashboard

Get info for a particular dashboard: https://jira-server/rest/api/2/dashboard/{dashboard-id}

More info here: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.1.html#d2e816